# Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server: s3 with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-storage

I am developing a web application using Laravel. In my application, I develop a feature for uploading the file to the server. But, I will store the files in the Amazon S3 bucket instead. So, I am just following the Laravel official documentation - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem. But I am getting an error.

First I run this command to install required package in the terminal

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3
```

Then in the environment file, I added these variable

```
AWS_IAM_KEY=xxxxxxx
AWS_IAM_SECRET=xvxxxx
AWS_REGION=eu-west-2
AWS_BUCKET=xxxxxxx
```

Then in the controller, I upload like this.

```
$request->file('photo_file')->store(
      'activity_files/'.uniqid(), 's3'
 );
```

When I upload the file, it is giving me this error.

```
Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. (cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 169.254.169.254 port 80: Network unreachable (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html))
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you registered in Amazon S3 service and checked that your account is working?

Comment: Yes. It is working

Comment: Have you configured security groups - ip whitelist, port 80 access, etc.?

Comment: can you try with `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` as env variable names

Comment: This error "Failed to connect to 169.254.169.254 port 80 Network unreachable" indicates that you have a network problem. Something is broken in your VPC, route table, OS firewall, etc. I am betting OS route table. What does your route table look like from inside the instance?

Comment: No, this error indicates that the application/SDK is trying to fetch [AWS EC2 instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) to retrieve the credentials (and fails since it is not running on EC2 instance)

Comment: Now. I got it working. I don't know what the error is. I just created the new s3 bucket and used it instead.

Comment: A reminder again, Wai, that please-halp-me begging is unnecessary here. Keep questions succinct - pleading is irritating to current and future readers, and does not actually hurry the obtaining of answers.